# How do I underexpose a camera image in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to get the camera on my Windows Phone to take an underexposed image. I've gone through the [PhotoCamera](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.photocamera%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class documentation as well as this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wp7mangotrainingcourse_photofunlab_topic2). While I can access the raw camera data and manipulate the buffer before the image is saved this is not sufficient as I need to modify the camera's capture setting.

I'm trying to prevent the highlights from blowing out, because the camera's metering has been fooled by the scene and has decided to overexpose. When the highlights are blown out, the RGB values are 255, 255, 255 and there's nothing I can do to recover any lost detail.

On my non-phone camera, it's common to underexpose such scenes by using the EV compensation facility. Am I missing something or does Windows Phone 7.5 really lack such basic camera functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows Phone 7 camera always selects an exposure time automatically. The only control the user has over this is the 'metering mode', where they can tell the camera to expose based on the average image intensity, or the centre of the image.

Unfortunately you cannot change this setting through the camera API.

Comment: It's a shame that Windows Phone lacks such simple functionality, but it was what I expected after reading through the MSDN docs. Thanks for confirming that I wasn't missing something obvious.